# Android: Put 5 listviews in the same layout, ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have 5 listviews which I would like to put in the same layout.
My idea was to use a scrollview but apparently this is not working very well.

How could i do this.

Thank you.

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_white" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_mdpi" />


 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/SearchingForTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:text="Searching for: "
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
     android:textColor="#ff000000"
     android:visibility="visible" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SearchingFor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/SearchingForTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Word"
    android:textColor="#112ED4"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/JournalsSearchTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SearchingFor"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ff888888"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Journals"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/JournalSearchListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/JournalsSearchTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#D5DADE"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ArticlesSearchTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/JournalSearchListView"
    android:background="#ff888888"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Articles"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/ArticlesIssuesSearchListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ArticlesSearchTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#D5DADE"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
</ListView>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AuthorsSearchTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ArticlesIssuesSearchListView"
    android:background="#ff888888"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Authors"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/AuthorsSearchListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AuthorsSearchTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#D5DADE"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SubmissionsSearchTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AuthorsSearchListView"
    android:background="#ff888888"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Submissions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/SubmissionsSearchListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SubmissionsSearchTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#D5DADE"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/SpecialIssuesSearchTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SubmissionsSearchListView"
    android:background="#ff888888"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Special Issues"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/SpecialIssuesSearchListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SpecialIssuesSearchTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#D5DADE"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Its always a bad idea to put scrollable controls into a scrollable container. It's hard for the system to know, if you want to scroll in one of the listviews or if you want to scroll the container. Is it nessecary to see all five listviews at the same time? otherwise i would suggest to build five adapters and change them. What do you want to do?

Comment: In fact, the 5 listviews shuld only be in the same layout, but not necessery seen at the same time. For example, I don't need that the listview is scrollable because I will have maximum 10 itms in each listview. But even with 10 items per list, their size is higher than the screen size so i would like to give the possibility to the user to scroll and see eveerything.

Comment: @Ana can you tell me why 5 listview in one layout ?

Comment: Did you mean horizontal scroll with 5 different listview?

Comment: ok, unfortunally i fear you could not force the listview to be exact as high as the content, otherwise you would be able to use a vertical scrollview an add your five nonscrollable listviews. I would suggest to use one listview and add all the items in this one, but using a custom adapter with the possibility to let the items look different and/or perform different actions on Itemselect. Or you build 5 adapters and add some buttons to toggle between the adapters

Comment: @SamirMangroliya: In fact I have a search function, this function is looking for 5 different categories of results, for example a, b, c, d and e. Each result is obtained serparetly so i am populating separate listviews.

Comment: @Hanon No, I have an vertical scrollview with 5 diferent listviews

Comment: @2red13 Unfortunetly no, my listview can be max 10 items height but can olso be empty or 5 items height. In which concerns using one listview, I don't know if this is possible because I have more than one subitem per item.

Comment: Can you post some code for what you did?

Comment: @Hanon, yes, will be done immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what you want finally. You want to show the search result for 5 different categories.

I suggest you can use a ExpandableListView for this. 
Android offer an ExpandableListView which look like the following structures:

```
Group A       (v)
-----------------
  Child A1
-----------------
  Child A2
-----------------
  Child A3
-----------------
Group B       (v)
-----------------
  Child B1
-----------------
  Child B2
-----------------
  Child B3
-----------------
Group C       (v)
-----------------
  Child C1
-----------------
  Child C2
-----------------
  Child C3
```

The usage is quite similar to the ListView. What you have to do is to write an adapter which extends BaseExpandableListAdapter. 
You can also implements custom layout for the Group view/Child view.

You may refer these pages:

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

http://www.techienjoy.com/android-expandable-list-dynamically-created-example.php

http://android-adda.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html

Comment: Thank you Hanon, I think that's what I need. Is there a possibility to have only the titles in the listView and not the expanations?

I will try to implement this.

Comment: Yes, you can customize the group/children view with your custom xml layout.

Comment: Would you mind expanding this answer so that it stands on its own if the links break? Just summarize the information they contain.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your `ListView`s to be scrollable, as you've mentioned in the comment, and the lists would contain up to ~10 items, I would consider using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ListView`, and put all 5 `LinearLayout`s inside a big `ScrollView`.

EDIT: code example:

Layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

Code:

```
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
for (String s : arrayList1) {
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText(s);
  list.addView(s);
}
for (String s : arrayList2) {
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText(s);
  list.addView(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you marmor, This can be a good idea, do you have an example please? and also, if I will use 5 LinearLayouts, how can I populate them and is there a posibility to have an listener per linearLayout?

Comment: Thank you, but there is something I am ton understanding, what is the TextView in your code and also the ViewGroup. I have my data in a ArrayList<String> and don't know how to populate then the LinearLayout.

Comment: An it is written that ScrollView can host only one child

Comment: You're partially right about the ScrollView, it's basically a FrameLayout which can contain more then one-child, though it's a bit more complicated to control. Anyway, I've modified my answer, so it's one big LinearLayout, that contains strings from 2 ArrayList<String>, but if that fit your needs, you may just as well use one ListView as well.

Comment: One more question marmor, could you please tell me, if I am using your first solution with the LinearLayout, how can I know which item of the LinearLayout (list) is clicked. I put an onClickListener and I am getting the clicks but how can I know which of those textViews is clicked.